# bundle install failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, devise, bundler

I am getting this error on bundle install

```
Gem::InstallError: devise_invitable requires RubyGems version ~> 1.3.6. Try 'gem update --system' to update RubyGems itself.
An error occured while installing devise_invitable (0.4.rc), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install devise_invitable -v '0.4.rc'` succeeds before bundling.
```

but when i see the version of rubygems i have

```
gem -v
1.8.10
```

any ideas on how to fix this....here is the top of my gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.3'
gem 'devise', "1.2.rc"
gem 'devise_invitable', '0.4.rc'
```

Comment: yes i am using rvm ....rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p290@myapp

Comment: Please try running `rvm 1.9.2 do gem -v` and if it is old then `rvm 1.9.2 do gem update --system`

Comment: doing rvm 1.9.2 do gem -v
1.8.15

Comment: but i still get the error Gem::InstallError: devise_invitable requires RubyGems version ~> 1.3.6. Try 'gem update --system' to update RubyGems itself.

Comment: What happens after doing `'gem update --system` ?

Answer (score 0):

In the gemspec for devise_invitable, they explicitly require rubygems, ruby and bundler with specific version constraints. While they look like they should be ok since they are using `>=`, the fact that it comes out in your console as `~>` is telling.

The requirement of `~> 1.3.6` means you need to have a version of rubygems installed that is 1.3.6 <= x < 1.4.0.

1. You could try running `bundle install` to get compatible gem versions
2. But if that doesn't work, try installing the version explicitly `gem install rubygems -v 1.3.6`

Comment: does anyone know whether it is required to explicitly require those items when using ruby 1.8? Or is it bad practice like in ruby 1.9? see (http://tomayko.com/writings/require-rubygems-antipattern)